# Assigning labels to the detected points

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I am working on tracking a human. I have calculated the centroid and points(Head,hands and legs). Depending on the image, these points can be at maximum 5 or at least 2 depending on the pose of the person. I want to assign labels like left leg,right leg, left hand, right hand and head to these points. But the problem is that unless i plot them i dont know which point is what.
I want to use some logic like if its above centroid then head or below centroid then legs or some other idea/heuristics but i dont know if its possible in Matlab. I am attaching an image with detected points and centroid. I will appreciate if anyone can suggest some ideas.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the centroids xy coordinates and those of these point you can just make logic based on this, right?

please provide some code. I do not understand your question.

EDIT:

For instance: `matrix_with_point = [0.5 1;0.25 0.5;0.75 0.5];` and `centroid = [0.5 0.5]` with colnum 1 being x and 2 being y then:

```
for i = 1:size(matrix_with_point,1)
      %check x direction
      if matrix_with_points(i,1) < centroid(1,1) %left
      % however you would like to label
      text(matrix_with_point(i,1),matrix_with_point(i,2),'Left')
      elseif matrix_with_points(i,1) >= centroid(1,1) %right
      % however you would like to label
      text(matrix_with_point(i,1),matrix_with_point(i,2),'Right')


      end
end
```

you can gone but you get it I think?

Comment: Yes, i do have centroids x y cordinates and the xy cordinates of the points.  I have a vector/array e.g. Points with five points or less, centroids xy, and boundary of the person. Now i want to find out which of the points from the array is head,legs and hands. I want to use the logic if its above the centroid then its head and so on. But dont know how to do it

Comment: Can you explain your logic a bit more.

Comment: Thanks alot, I understand it now.